# Find Employee name who is having highest salary in given month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by

I have two tables first one is Employee and second one is Salary.

Employee:

[image: Employee]

Salary:

[image: Salary]

This is the structure of both tables and I need to find the name of the person who has got highest salary in Feb 2014.

I tried by below Query but not getting correct output.

```
select first_name+' '+last_name as Name from Employee where 
(select top(1)empid from Salary order by salary_amt desc)
```

Comment: well, `salary_month` is a `DATE`, how are the values stored for Feb 2014? (hint: you need to add that condition somewhere in your query)

Comment: @Lamak Salary month stored as 2014-02-28

Comment: is `salary_amt` `nvarchar` ? you need to cast that to a `numeric` type first, then `order` that by `descending` to get first row

Answer (score 2):

Youcan just join the first and second table on empId. Use max(salary_amt) and make sure you add the date condition in your where clause as @Lamak mentioned

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

select 
empID,
first_name,
last_name,
sum(salary_amt) as salary_in_month
from
salary s
join employee e on s.empID=e.empID
where
month(salary_month)=2
and year(salary_month)=2014
group by empID
order by sum(salary_amt) desc
limit 1

Answer (score 1):

```
select first_name+' '+last_name as Name 
from Employee e
    join Salary s
        On s.EmpId = e.EmpId
           and salary_Month = 'Feb 2014'
           and cast(s.Salary_amt as money) =
              (Select Max(cast(Salary_amt as money)) 
               from salary
               Where salary_Month = 'Feb 2014')
```

NOTE:  There should be a unique alternate composite key on Salary.Salary_month and Salary.empId.

Comment: I'm not so sure this would work. I mean, outside of the fact that `salary_amt` is a varchar and that `salary_month` is a date, the where condition makes it seem like it's calculating the max salary for each employee

Comment: @Lamak,  Yes, good catch, thanks! I have edited to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends for your answers. I changed the data type of `salary_amt` to money and working answer is:

```
select top(1)first_name+' '+last_name as Name 
from Employee e
join Salary s
On s.EmpId = e.EmpId
and salary_Month = 'Feb 2014' order by salary_amt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Empp has two columns = id,name
Salary has four columns = sal_id,id,sal,month

Let the given month be "jan"

```
SELECT E1.name, S1.sal FROM Empp E1 INNER JOIN salary S1 ON E1.id = S1.id where 
S1.sal = (select max(S2.sal) from Salary S2
where S2.month='jan');
```